# The body part of email sent through ezgmail splited into several lines. (Python 3.8 in Pycharm)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I tried to send email generated by Ezgmail and received the body of the email in several lines.

Here is what I did:

```
import ezgmail

recipient = 'abcde@abc.com'
subject = 'Attention: email is generated by Ezgmail.'
body = 'This is a testing email generated by Ezgmail on Pycharm under Python 3.8, however the body part is separated into multiple lines whilst the whole part is a single string.'

ezgmail.send(recipient, subject, body)
```

The body of the email I received is not a long sentence which it should be, but like below:

```
This is a testing email generated by Ezgmail on Pycharm
under Python 3.8, however the body part is 
separated into multiple lines whilst the whole part
is a single string.
```

So how can I have the body part a long sentence?
Is that because Ezgmail limited each line of email body to a specific length?
Thank you guys.

Comment: Try inserting r before the body string. Which makes the string raw: r'This is a....

Comment: I would check ezgmail. On mail, lines should never be longer then 998 characters (it will be very inefficient to allocate dynamic buffers frequently for large lines. Paragraphs are divided by a empty line, etc. Check how text mail client interpret strings.

Comment: @AlexRika I tried, but unfortunately, it doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I send more emails to different providers, it seems that only Gmail can reflect the correct format, maybe that's why it called ezGmail.  I should check the source code of the module (I don't think I may understand it though lol).